# Codeigniter add new item to current session userdata array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

So I have this array:

```
$data = array(
  'item_1' => $this->input->post('item_1'),
  'item_2' => $this->input->post('item_2'),
  'item_3' => $this->input->post('item_3')
);

$this->session->set_userdata( 'items', $data );
```

And I want to add a new item to that array, so the updated array of userdata will be like this:

```
$data = array(
      'item_1' => $this->input->post('item_1'),
      'item_2' => $this->input->post('item_2'),
      'item_3' => $this->input->post('item_3'),
      'item_4' => $this->input->post('item_4')
);

$this->session->set_userdata( 'items', $data );
```

How to do that, Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Follow these steps to add data to the current session:

```
$data            = $this->session->userdata('items');
$data['item_4']  = $this->input->post('item_4');
$this->session->set_userdata('items', $data);
```

Here, we first take out the `current session items` in an array, add another item to the array, you can do a `array_push()` but I prefer the above. Now, set the session back with the updated data.

Answer (score 2):

Got this from [ellislab](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html):

> **Adding Custom Session Data**
>
> A useful aspect of the session array is that you can add your own data to it and it will be stored in the user's cookie. Why would you want to do this? Here's one example:
>
> Let's say a particular user logs into your site. Once authenticated, you could add their username and email address to the session cookie, making that data globally available to you without having to run a database query when you need it.
>
> To add your data to the session array involves passing an array containing your new data to this function:
>   $this->session->set_userdata($array);
>
> Where $array is an associative array containing your new data. Here's an example:

```
$newdata = array(
   'username'  => 'johndoe',
   'email'     => 'johndoe@some-site.com',
   'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

> If you want to add userdata one value at a time, set_userdata() also supports this syntax.

```
$this->session->set_userdata('some_name', 'some_value');
```

So in essence you should be able to create the item you want to add and then add it to the session by using `$this->session->set_userdata("item_4", "item_4");` or `$this->session->set_userdata($newdata)` if you want to add many items .